# Ruby On Rails 4, Merge two AR objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I do if I want to merge two active records in Rails 4?

Doing (in console)

```
@foo = User.find(1)
@bar = User.find(2)
@foo << @bar
```

Results:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<User:...
```

Comment: How do you mean by "merge two active records"? What result do you expect to get?

Comment: @toro2k I want to be able to fetch user 1 and 2 with "@foo"

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to achieve, please?

Comment: Ehh okay? Isn't that what I've done already? I have a view that renders all users that are under @foo, I want to be able to add users to an already existing array with other users in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the objects already you need an array to store them:

```
@foo = []
@foo << User.find(1)
@foo << User.find(2)
```

Comment: That isn't a solution here, I use advanced queries from witch I want to merge all to one array.

Comment: @Philip, either you explain better yourself, or we will be guessing all day long. His solution is what you are looking for regardless of the complexity of a query.

Comment: Thanks, that was the way to go.

Comment: or @foo = User.find([1,2]) or use a "raw" sequel query: ActiveRecord::Base.connection().execute("select * from users where id IN (1,2)"). Though I am very very curious why you would want this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foo = User.where(id: 1)

@bar = User.where(id: 2)

@foo << @bar
@foo
```

`@foo` would return a merge of both, I am sure this works in Mongoid so should work conveniently in ActiveRecord

Comment: Does a `.where()` in MongoID return an array? That would explain why the << works.

Comment: A where statement always return an array, however with the << processor it merges the array into the other ie: [object1, [object2]]

Comment: @dennis what it returns is [object1, object2] in mongoid it is not an array but an object that behaves like an array

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `@foo = User.find_all_by_id([1, 2])` fits the bill. "Unfortunately", because this rewards Philip for continuing to use the term "merge" wrong!

Comment: Beware that this method returns an empty array when the objects cannot be found, this may result in some unexpected behaviour, when using the find() it will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Exception which is convenient imo.

Comment: You have a typo there. You were clearly trying to write "As an added benefit, this method returns an empty array when the objects cannot be found..."

Comment: I think it does have benefits, however when searching for id attributes I wouldn't want to skip the RecordNotFound error.